# How to install packages and libraries for c # on repl.it

Tags: c#, installation, package, replit

so i am using this online website called https://repl.it/ , so I am actually learning C# in it so i wanted to try some packages and libraries but I don't know how to access them. So i was wondering if anyone could help.I have tried watching some you tube videos but I couldn't find any so please help me.

Answer (score 3):

For new C# repls that use .Net Core (as opposed to .Net Framework via Mono), this is quite straightforward.

1. Create a C# Repl

[image: New Repl Dialog]

2. Select the Packages Tab (icon looks like an isometric cube)

[image: Packages Tab]

3. Search for the package you want and click the `+` button

[image: Add a Package]

4. Alternatively, use the dotnet command line in the shell

[image: dotnet command line]

Answer (score -1):

Repl.it currently doesn't support packages for C#. Only for Python and Js

Comment: This is outdated information. It used to be that C# repls did not support package installation via the Replit.com UI and did not have either the dotnet CLI or nuget CLI installed. However, if you create a new C# repl today they now support package installation both via the UI and using the `dotnet nuget` command line. I'm just posting this as a comment for now because I don't have time to write up thorough instructions.